# Overload c() or modify base::det?

Tags: r, concatenation, overloading, r-s4, determinants

I have overloaded the `determinant` function for a S4 class in R. The base `determinant` function returns a list with elements `modulus` and `sign`; the values, however, are my S4 objects (for which `*` is overloaded). I then redefined the `det` function (I had to dig through the source code of the `Matrix` package to figure out how to do this, which was  a horrorshow in its own right.) to be `base::det` with my environment.

For reasons I do not understand, `base::det` is defined as follows:

```
function (x, ...) 
{
    z <- determinant(x, logarithm = TRUE, ...)
    c(z$sign * exp(z$modulus))
}
```

When called on my object, the `z` is computed as expected, and `z$sign` and `z$modulus` are fine. I have overloaded `*` and `exp` so that `z$sign * exp(z$modulus)` evaluates to one of my objects.

**BUT WHY THE** `c` **?**

When wrapped in `c()` the return value is no longer a scalar numeric, but a *list* with one element in it: my object. This is not what I want, and it breaks my unit tests. Some optional workarounds:

1. Rewrite `det`, possibly breaking whatever required use of `c()`.
2. Somehow overload `c()` (or is it `as.vector`?) for my object. I am not even sure how to do that.
3. Something else?

What is the recommended solution, and how should I proceed?  Extra points for the proper way to document this mess with `roxygen2`.

(For reference, the package is now on github at https://github.com/shabbychef/madness )

**EDIT** 
The MWE would look as follows:

```
require(devtools)
install_github("shabbychef/madness")
require(madness)
xmat <- matrix(rnorm(16),ncol=4)
xmad <- madness(xmat)
detv <- det(xmad)
# detv is a list. I want it to be a madness object:
str(detv)
what_i_want <- detv[[1]]
str(what_i_want)
```

Comment: What exactly do you want this function to return? Something other than a numeric value? The `c()` should just be stripping the class information basically. It would help if you included a self-contained, minimal [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) in your question.

Comment: @MrFlick The object contains the computed value and the derivative with respect to some other quantity (via forward differentiation). I would like that object to be returned. One can treat it as a numeric via `as.numeric` if needed. I will cook up a MWE.

Comment: `c()` is already a generic function (see `methods(c)`). You can define a method for your class if that would make sense. This link may help with that: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html#s4

Comment: I think I got it: the `c()` exists to strip the _attributes_ from `z$modulus` and `z$sign`, and I have to think of a way of vectorizing my objects; and `c.objectname` is the way to do that.